# Currently having a bug where not all of the squares reset in my Etch-A_Sketch game, what could be the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
let reset = document.querySelector("button");
let board = document.querySelector(".board-container");

reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
  resetSize();
});

function resetSize() {
  let number = prompt("What size would you like the baord to be? (1-100)");
  board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
  board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${number}, 1fr)`;
  createBoard(number);
}

function createBoard(boardSize) {
  board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${boardSize}, 1fr)`;
  board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${boardSize}, 1fr)`;

  for (let i = 0; i < boardSize * boardSize; i++) {
    let square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    board.appendChild(square);

    square.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
      square.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    });

    function resetBoard() {
      reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
        square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      });
    }
  }

  resetBoard();
}

createBoard(60);
```

Most of the squares reset but not all. What can be the issue? Most of them reset, but at least 5% of the squares will show has the "mouseover" color and at least 2 of them will always appear as white. I am wondering why not all of the squares reset to the the initial color of "orange" after I press the reset button.

I am expecting all of the squares to reset. However, some of them randomly decide to be either the mouseover color or white.